# covering each side of a cube with different images- OpenGL

Tags: c++, opengl, textures

I have this cube and I want to cover each side of it with a different image in which a letter appears.

[image]

My problem is that cube is covered by the same image, as you can see in following image. 
but I want that letter A appears on top, B on left side and C on right side.

[image]

in order to convert/transform images (letters A,B,C) in textures I use this code:

```
glGenTextures(1, textureA);
    glGenTextures(1, textureB);
    glGenTextures(1, textureC);
    glClearColor (0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
      if (flagA ==1){
            cvtColor(imageA, imageA, CV_BGR2RGB);
            glHint(GL_PERSPECTIVE_CORRECTION_HINT,GL_NICEST);
            glPixelStorei(GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT, 1);
            glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, textureA);
            glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D,GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER,GL_LINEAR);
            glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D,GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER,GL_LINEAR);
            //glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, 4,image.cols, image.rows, 0, GL_RGB,GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, image.data);
            gluBuild2DMipmaps(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_RGB, imageA.cols, imageA.rows, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, imageA.data);
        }
        if (flagC ==1){
            cvtColor(imageC, imageC, CV_BGR2RGB);
            glHint(GL_PERSPECTIVE_CORRECTION_HINT,GL_NICEST);
            glPixelStorei(GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT, 1);
            glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, textureC);
            glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D,GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER,GL_LINEAR);
            glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D,GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER,GL_LINEAR);
            //glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, 4,image.cols, image.rows, 0, GL_RGB,GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, image.data);
            gluBuild2DMipmaps(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_RGB, imageC.cols, imageC.rows, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, imageC.data);
        }
        if (flagB ==1){
            cvtColor(imageB, imageB, CV_BGR2RGB);
            glHint(GL_PERSPECTIVE_CORRECTION_HINT,GL_NICEST);
            glPixelStorei(GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT, 1);
            glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, textureB);
            glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D,GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER,GL_LINEAR);
            glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D,GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER,GL_LINEAR);
            //glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, 4,image.cols, image.rows, 0, GL_RGB,GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, image.data);
            gluBuild2DMipmaps(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_RGB, imageB.cols, imageB.rows, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, imageB.data);
        }
```

I noted that if I switch block `if(flagB==1){...}` with `if(flagC==1){...}` (in this way image with C letter is the last in process of image-texture transformation), my cube is covered only by C letters.

Why this strange behaviour?

In order to display the result, I use this code:

```
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);

glMatrixMode (GL_PROJECTION);
glLoadIdentity();
gluOrtho2D(0, WIDTH, HEIGHT, 0); 

glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
glLoadIdentity(); 

if(flagA==1){
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, textureA);
    glBegin(GL_QUADS);
    glTexCoord2f(0.0f, 0.0f); glVertex2f((GLfloat)((A[3].x)),(GLfloat)(A[3].y));
    glTexCoord2f(1.0f, 0.0f); glVertex2f((GLfloat)((A[0].x)),(GLfloat)(A[0].y));
    glTexCoord2f(1.0f, 1.0f); glVertex2f((GLfloat)((A[1].x)),(GLfloat)(A[1].y));
    glTexCoord2f(0.0f, 1.0f); glVertex2f((GLfloat)((A[2].x)),(GLfloat)(A[2].y));
    glEnd();
    }
    if(flagB==1){
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, textureB);
    glBegin(GL_QUADS);
    glTexCoord2f(0.0f, 0.0f); glVertex2f((GLfloat)((B[3].x)),(GLfloat)(B[3].y));
    glTexCoord2f(1.0f, 0.0f); glVertex2f((GLfloat)((B[0].x)),(GLfloat)(B[0].y));
    glTexCoord2f(1.0f, 1.0f); glVertex2f((GLfloat)((B[1].x)),(GLfloat)(B[1].y));
    glTexCoord2f(0.0f, 1.0f); glVertex2f((GLfloat)((B[2].x)),(GLfloat)(B[2].y));
    glEnd();
    }
    if(flagC==1){
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, textureC);
    glBegin(GL_QUADS);
    glTexCoord2f(0.0f, 0.0f); glVertex2f((GLfloat)((C[3].x)),(GLfloat)(C[3].y));
    glTexCoord2f(1.0f, 0.0f); glVertex2f((GLfloat)((C[0].x)),(GLfloat)(C[0].y));
    glTexCoord2f(1.0f, 1.0f); glVertex2f((GLfloat)((C[1].x)),(GLfloat)(C[1].y));
    glTexCoord2f(0.0f, 1.0f); glVertex2f((GLfloat)((C[2].x)),(GLfloat)(C[2].y));
    glEnd();
    }
```

I work on windows7 x64 and OpenGL.

Answer (score 0):

We don't see your rendering code.

Did you write this somewhere to generate the texture ids ?

```
glGenTextures(1, &textureA);
glGenTextures(1, &textureB);
glGenTextures(1, &textureC);
```

Did you write this when you are rendering your cube ?

```
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, textureA);
// Draw the A face 

glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, textureB);
// Draw the B face 

glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, textureC);
```

// Draw the C face

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing is:

```
glGenTextures(1, textureA);
glGenTextures(1, textureB);
glGenTextures(1, textureC);
```

It should be:

```
glGenTextures(1, &textureA);
glGenTextures(1, &textureB);
glGenTextures(1, &textureC);
```

I assume the problem happens because the variables textureA, textureB and textureC do not get valid values and therefore glBindTexture calls are doing nothing (although i think you should have got segmentation fault).